# How to populate objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

What am i trying to do is a single todo app where you can create user and log in with that user.Every user can CRUD for single todo and can fetch all of the todos that are linked to that particular user.
this is the schema for the userSchema

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
firstName:{type:String,trim:true},
lastName:{type:String,trim:true},
userName:{type:String,required:true,unique:true,sparse:true,trim:true},
email:{type:String,required:true,unique:true,sparse:true,trim:true},
phoneNumber:{type:String,unique:true,sparse:true,required:true},
hash:{type:String,required:true}
})
```

and i have todoSchema

```
 author:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
title:{type:String, required:true, trim:true},
context:{type:String, trim:true,},
isFinished:{type:Boolean,required:true,default: false},
finishedAt:{type:Date}
```

Also i have login system that works with JWT,My question is how can i save  todo with the id of the user that is currently logged in..And also how can i fetch all todos that are linked to the user that is currently logged in
I dont want todos to be stored in userSchema as array,rather as different schema where you can do CRUD for each todo
-I was reading something called populate that comes with mongoose but i dont know how to implement that
--It will be very nice if you can give me some ideas how to do that..I don't need full implementation..Thank you

-If you  need more of the code here it is https://github.com/jkuzmanovik/todoApi

Answer (score 1):

Once the user is logged in ( I guess you are using passport ) passport creates req.user which can be. req.user will contain all the details given in the user schema while creating passport plugin.

This can be used to populate your toDo schema like follows:

in the get request you do

`toDo.find({})
.populate('author') 
...`

But if your goal is to find all toDos by the user you can do as follows

```
toDo.find({author:req.user._id})
```

This can be done only after authentication.
This will get you all the todos by the user.

PS: Once you populate only the author field will be replaced (not the proper word but understandable) by the user object itself, it does not help in filtering. Mongoose population should be used meticulously as it is database resource hungry and will reduce the server performance.

About JWT, whenever you make a req you need to pass the JWT to the server (by URL, authorization header etc.). There is a method called extract which will extract the user from the JWT token and thus authentication is possible. 
More about that read documentation on passport-jwt and jsonwebtoken.